# Compiling Android 12 for Orange PI5+

Tags: android, linux, compilation

Can you please tell me how to properly configure Android 12 kernel for Orange PI5+ single board computer on rockchip rk3588 chip?

The manufacturer gives the source code of Android 12 AOSP.

You need to download, unpack and compile uboot, kernel, android and pack them into update.img
By executing the commands in turn:

```
test@test:~$ cd Android_12
test@test:~/ Android_12$ source build/envsetup.sh
test@test:~/ Android_12$ lunch rk3588_s-userdebug
test@test:~/ Android_12$ ./build.sh -AUKu
```

But how can I add support to the firmware, for example, a GPS receiver on a u-blox, neo-m8 chip
If you compile this firmware by default, then there is no GPS support in it.

But in the source code, I see a GPS driver in the `/kernel-5.10/drivers/gnss` folder, but I can't figure out how to include it in my assembly.
Also in the `/vendor/rockchip/common/gps/ap6xxx` folder is the `gps.default.so` library, which is not in the compiled firmware. But how do I add a GPS driver to the kernel, I don't understand.

By looking on the Internet, I found that you can configure the kernel using `menuconfig`, with the `make menuconfig` command, but I can’t figure out how to use it

How can I do this?

Comment: This might be a better question for [android.se]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your try, I mannaged to get things working here, not the GPS U-Blox Neo-6M, but finnaly I did the compilation with -userdebug and worked. Need to Install first RKTool with some options It booted in Android 12 Enviroment, but now I will try to change some options in .config to compile the GNSS module in Kernel and see if it solve this issue of no Internel GPS. I can see by wiringOP the ttyS3 showing the data of my U-Blox in UART section with 9600 Baud rate, and is the only baud that works.

Comment: Dear, can you share with me instructions on how to add GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Hot news from the front, to compile kernel, just enter in kernel-5.10 folder and do make menuconfig than copy .config (save your compilation) as your kernel config.

Then:

```bash
make && make modules && make modules install
```

Do the `./build.sh -AUKu` to incorporate the new kernel.

Best regards,
Fernando.